# compare two dates in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I am sure this question came up before I am pulling my hair out. I have two dates - one from an Object on Parse.com and the other one local. I try to determine whether the remote object has been updated so that I can trigger actions locally.

When looking at the NSDate of both objects they seem identical but a comparison reveals that the remote object is newer - when checking the time internal (since1970) it becomes obvious that there is a difference but why? When I first created the local object all I did was

```
localObject.updatedAt = remoteObject.updatedAt //both NSDate
```

But when looking closer I get this:

```
Local Time Interval: 1411175940.000000
Local Time: 2014-09-20 01:19:00 +0000
Remote Time Interval: 1411175940.168000
Remote Time: 2014-09-20 01:19:00 +0000
```

Does anyone have an idea why that is and whether I can ignore this detail? Does iOS round up or something?

Adding more code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *date;    
...    
PFQuery *query = [PFObject query];
[query whereKey:@"Product" equalTo:@"123456"]
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {
        self.date = objects[0].updatedAt;
        NSTimeInterval localTime = [self.date timeIntervalSince1970];
        NSTimeInterval remoteTime = [objects[0].updatedAt timeIntervalSince1970];
        NSLog(@"Local Time Interval: %f", localTime);
        NSLog(@"Local Time: %@", self.date);
        NSLog(@"Remote Time Interval: %f", remoteTime);
        NSLog(@"Remote Time: %@", objects[0].updatedAt);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error with query");
    }
}];
```

That results in the console output above - and I don't understand why these dates are different.

Comment: We're gonna need to see more code than this.

Comment: 1. How to do compare the dates? 2. Use `-timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`. What is the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse stores dates as iso8601 format. This makes things very complex as Apple does not manage the format well. While the idea of the standard is awesome, until everyone plays by the same rules, anarchy rules..

I convert everything inbound from parse into usable format before attempting anything on their date time values..

Drop this into a library somewhere, and save yourself tons of headaches. This took weeks of searching and scratching to overcome.

```
+ (NSDate *)convertParseDate:(NSDate *)sourceDate {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    NSString *input = (NSString *)sourceDate;
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
    // Always use this locale when parsing fixed format date strings
    NSLocale* posix = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    dateFormatter.locale = posix;
    NSDate *convertedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:input];

    assert(convertedDate != nil);
    return convertedDate;
}
```

Comment: And by the way - for me there was so much scratching involved I am bold now

Comment: Why the cast from `NSDate` to `NSString`?

Comment: the string was required to toss back into the date formatter.. honestly, i don't recall all the myriad of gyrations required to make this work, it was truly a beast. I'd welcome any simpler manner to have the same end-rsult, all i know is that it works, and i was able to move on to more important tasks. As issue was the ability to render proper analysis of a timestamp into "today" "yesterday" etc.. it was a bit of a nightmare ;)

Comment: It seems logical to make the parameter (`sourceDate`) an `NSString` in the first place, as that's obviously what it is (else exceptions would be raised).  In order to use that method, and make the compiler happy, you'd have to cast in the opposite direction.

Comment: @user3757285 you've accepted this answer, however I don't see how it relates to your question which explicitly states you are creating `NSDate` objects from time intervals and are having problems with rounding. Anyone finding this answer won't be helped by it (regardless of how useful it actually is WRT parsing ISO 8601-formatted dates).

Comment: @trojanfoe: the question centred around *why* the dates were different. I explained why, as i encountered the same issue. I posted how to manage the difference. And i hope it helps others. cheers.

Comment: @drewatparseforumsdotcom.. Well as I mentioned in my comment, it's difficult to see how this answer relates to the question given the OP's use of time intervals.  There is no mention of date formats in the question.

Comment: This will be my last comment on this thread, but this is so indicative of why many dislike SO.. so stuck in a myriad of picky comments. To quote the original post: 
"When looking at the NSDate of both objects they seem identical but a comparison reveals that the remote object is newer - when checking the time internal (since1970) it becomes obvious that there is a difference but why? "

If you read that properly you will see the "why" relates to the question as to why the dates are different. I answered why. period.

Comment: that is stated already: "Parse stores dates as iso8601 format".

Answer (score 3):

I cannot explain *why* there is a difference, but the important thing to understand is that there can be a difference and that when comparing dates you *have to use a tolerance value*.

The Apple [*Date and Time Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtDates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000183-SW5) has an example of how to compare two dates within a given tolerance:

> To compare dates, you can use the `isEqualToDate:`, `compare:`,
>   `laterDate:`, and `earlierDate:` methods. These methods perform exact
>   comparisons, which means they detect sub-second differences between
>   dates. You may want to compare dates with a less fine granularity. For
>   example, you may want to consider two dates equal if they are within a
>   minute of each other. If this is the case, use `timeIntervalSinceDate:`
>   to compare the two dates. The following code fragment shows how to use
>   `timeIntervalSinceDate:` to see if two dates are within one minute (60
>   seconds) of each other.
>
> ```
> if (fabs([date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1]) < 60) ...
> ```

It's up to you decide on the tolerance value, but something like 0.5 seconds seems reasonable:

```
+ (BOOL)date:(NSDate *)date1
  equalsDate:(NSDate *)date2
{
    return fabs([date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1]) < 0.5;
}
```

Comment: But also after reading the docs, know that they are a big old and don't cover some nice newer api. Be sure to watch the WWDC 2013 videos on calendrical calculation and look at the headers for the key classes, especially NSCalendar.

Comment: OK thanks guys - much appreciated. Still a mystery but at least now I know how to bypass that...thanks again